# How to change the link address from internal to external

Tags: javascript

Look at the line below
It now reads the file (script.js) from the same folder

I want to replace the link to another site for example: `https://site2.com/script.js`

```
wp_register_script(
    'post_publisher_js', 
    plugins_url('script.js', __FILE__),
    array( 'jquery' ),
    "1.0.2"
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `plugins_url('script.js', __FILE__)` with `'https://site2.com/script.js'`.

Comment: tnx tnxxxxxxxxxx